# Why does the following sentence use the word 'knowledges'?

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number

Consider the following question given in an English class for high school students in Myanmar:

> *Mg Mg has computer knowledge. Tun Tun has computer knowledge.*
>  (Given Answer word is *Both* _______).

We have to answer this question beginning with *Both*. One of the teachers gave his answer like this :

> *Both Mg Mg and Tun Tun have computer **knowledges**.*

I think that the *'s* at the end of *knowledge* is unnecessary. Am I correct?

Comment: "Knowledges" can be used to mean "types of knowledge" (e.g. scientific vs intuitive), but I'd say it's very rare to use the plural and the singular is normally better. Cite for plural: https://www.jstor.org/stable/20019938

Comment: Please tell us the source, provide some surrounding text, and give any other context you have knowledge of.

Comment: Yes,sir.In an English question paper of Myanmar for high school students ,it was given as follows: (Question-Mg Mg has computer knowledge.Tun Tun has computer knowledge.) (Given Answer word is Both---------).We have to answer this question beginning with Both.One of the teachers gave his answer like this : Both Mg Mg and Tun Tun have computer knowledges.I think this kind of sentence doesn't need to put 's' in the word of 'knowledge'. Am I wrong,sir?

Comment: You are not! However, 1. the context you just gave me should be included in the text of the question, and 2. the question should be moved to the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) StackExchange.

Comment: 'Knowledge' here, whatever the many ancient or obscure uses that might lead to using 's', is a mass noun like 'water'. 'The Pacific has water and the Atlantic has water. Both the Pacific and the Atlantic have water.' Same for 'knowledge'. Here it does not pluralize.

Comment: 'Knowledges' is so rare that only teachers / examiners with a very high proficiency would realise that the existence of the plural form makes the question far from easy (many probably assume that the non-count usage, which looks like the singular form, is the only one that can be considered). Indeed, most Anglophones are probably unaware of the validity of the plural form. Others, as perhaps here, may blithely  think that the plural form is idiomatic.// But please be aware

Comment: ... that questions are supposed to be accompanied by reasonable research, linked and attributed, on ELU. Wiktionary often shows rare plural forms other free online dictionaries pass on. // Does this answer your question? [knowledge or knowledges](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520923/knowledge-or-knowledges) Actually, no it doesn't, but it is an earlier duplicate of this question. With reasonable research (provided at the duplicate), this later one should be preferred, as it has the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.

Your teacher is not exactly wrong, but he is also not exactly right. Namely, in **most** contexts, native speakers would not pluralize *knowledge* in that sentence. Only in very specialized academic contexts would *knowledges* be appropriate.

Most dictionaries do not record *knowledges,* but the OED does, in several meanings. I will reproduce all of them, but it's 9.a. that seems relevant to your sentence.

> **II.** The fact or condition of knowing something.
>   **4.** 
>     **c.** With *of*. The fact or state of having a correct idea or understanding of something; the possession of information about something. Also with indefinite article; formerly also in *plural*.
>
> <sup>…
>
>   1670     T. S. & A. Roberts *Adventures Eng. Merchant* 146   They do it by the **Knowledges** that they have of Nature.
>
>   …</sup>
>
> **d.** As a count noun. An act of apprehending something with the mind; a perception, intuition, intimation, etc. *rare*.
>
> <sup>…
>
>   1626     T. Hawkins tr. N. Caussin *Holy Court* I. 123   To proceed..by such **knowledges**, as are common, with brute beastes, and forsake those of men.
>
>   1825     S. T. Coleridge *Aids Refl.* 160   It is the office..of Reason to bring a unity into all our conceptions and several **knowledges**.
>
>   a1856     W. Hamilton *Lect. Metaphysics* (1859) I. iii. 57   These two cognitions or **knowledges** have, accordingly, received different names.
>
>   1920     M. Austin No. 26 *Jayne St.* 241   Little **knowledges** of him like this came to her out of their enlarged intercourse, for they saw one another almost daily.</sup>
>
> **6.
>
>     a.** Chiefly with *of*. The fact or condition of having acquired a practical understanding or command of, or competence or skill in, a particular subject, language, etc., esp. through instruction, study, or practice; skill or expertise acquired in a particular subject, etc., through learning. Frequently with indefinite article. Formerly also with †*in* or infinitive.
>   <sup>In quot. 1787   in *plural*, indicating competence in more than one field.</sup>
>
> <sup>… 
>
>   1787     ‘P. Pindar’ *Lyric Odes to Royal Academicians* (ed. 5) iii. 9   With scarce more **knowledges** than these, He earns a Guinea ev'ry Day with ease.
>
>   …</sup>
>
> **III.** The object of knowing; something known or made known.
>   **9.**
>     **a.** As a count noun. A thing which is or may be known; *esp.* a branch of learning; a science; an art. Usually in *plural*.
>
> … 
>   <sup>1935     *Times* 5 Jan. 16/5   In the typical school to-day the time was so filled up with the learning of traditional **knowledges** and skills that little time was left for anything else.
>
>   1994    *Appl. Linguistics* **15** 127   A key part of Foucault's work is his analysis of how various **knowledges** and disciplines—medical..penitential, sexual, and so on—normalize social institutions and practices in society.</sup>

For example, the following books exist:

***Knowledges:*** Historical and Critical Studies in Disciplinarity (1993, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0gCGl3aK2OIC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=knowledges&source=gbs_navlinks_s)).
*Indigenous **Knowledges** in Global Contexts: Multiple Readings of Our World* (2000, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=of6XaWJS9cEC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=knowledges&source=gbs_navlinks_s)).
*Feminisms in Geography: Rethinking Space, Place, and **Knowledges*** (2008, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=z_7OPl1cQe4C&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=knowledges&source=gbs_navlinks_s)).

If you search Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA), you will find that out of 214 hits, all but two come from academic works. In the British National Corpus (BNC) it appears 22 times, and it seems that here, too, almost all of them come from academic publications.

Thus, *knowledges* does get used in academic contexts, but it is uncommon otherwise.

Comment: Yes,sir.In an English question paper of Myanmar for high school students ,it was given as follows: (Question-Mg Mg has computer knowledge.Tun Tun has computer knowledge.) (Given Answer word is Both---------).We have to answer this question beginning with Both.One of the teachers gave his answer like this : Both Mg Mg and Tun Tun have computer knowledges.I think this kind of sentence doesn't need to put 's' in the word of 'knowledge'. Am I wrong,sir?

Answer (score 0):

A better answer for filling in your blank following the word *both* than ?*knowledges* would be something more along the lines of 
of *kinds, types, sorts, varieties,* or *specializations*.

That’s because
we normally would use an “X-of-Y” construction here, where X is a
count noun and Y is a mass noun. For example:

- Both kinds of knowledge.
- Both types of knowledge.
- Both sorts of knowledge.
- Both varieties of knowledge.
- Both fields of knowledge.
- Both branches of knowledge.
- Both pieces of knowledge.

You can never say *both knowledge* in the singular because *both*
here acts as a quantifier meaning *the two*, and *both* must therefore
always be plural. The crucial point is that *knowledge* is nearly always used only as a mass
noun like *wedlock* or *greed*, and you cannot quantify something you 
cannot count.

Nonetheless, the OED does document two specialized subsenses of the word that use *knowledge* as a count noun. I include a pair of its citations for both of these:

> **II.** The fact or condition of knowing something.
>
> 4. d. As a count noun. An act of apprehending something with the mind; a perception, intuition, intimation, etc. *rare*.
>
>    - **1825**     Samuel Taylor Coleridge *Aids to reflection in the formation of a manly character on the several grounds of prudence, morality and religion* 160 
>        It is the office..of Reason to bring a unity into all our conceptions and several **knowledges**.
>    - **1920**     Mary Hunter Austin *No. 26 Jayne St.* 241 
>       Little **knowledges** of him like this came to her out of their enlarged intercourse, for they saw one another almost daily.
>
> **III.** The object of knowing; something known or made known.
>
> 9. a. As a count noun. A thing which is or may be known; esp. a branch of learning; a science; an art. Usually in *plural*.
>
>    - **1935**     *Times* 5 Jan. 16/5
>         In the typical school to-day the time was so filled up with the learning of traditional **knowledges** and skills that little time was left for anything else.
>    - **1994**     *Applied Linguistics* **15** 127
>         A key part of Foucault's work is his analysis of how various **knowledges** and disciplines—medical..penitential, sexual, and so on—normalize social institutions and practices in society.

I submit that those two are unusual senses, and that an X-of-Y partitive
constructive such as those I provided at the start of this post
would be the solution normally chosen by native speakers here 
for your scenario.